# Format timedelta as time zone offset string

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting, timedelta

As input I have two timestamp strings, one is a local time, other is the same moment in UTC time. I want to get the difference between them (basically to get local time zone offset) as string in specific format, e.g. +1100 or -0500.

```
import datetime

local = '2018-01-31 18:34:42.172'

utc = '2018-01-31 23:34:42.172'

local_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(local, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

utc_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(utc, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

offset_timedelta = local_dt - utc_dt

offset = offset_timedelta.total_seconds() / 3600

offset
Out[8]: -5.0
```

Using timedelta I can get offset as float (-5.0 for example above). From there I probably may create a function to turn that float to string in format I want, but I am curious if there's any datetime/timedelta method or formatting which I am missing, or some string format which would do the job with cleaner code and more efficient.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit, since I see my question is not clear:
Is there a way to get "-0500" I need (string in that specific format, not a float), either by datetime library or string formatting?

Comment: Throw it in a function if you want to clean up your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've actually done all the work already. But you can use the module `dateutil` to hide the messy details:

```
>>> local = '2018-01-31 18:34:42.172'
>>> utc = '2018-01-31 23:34:42.172'

>>> from dateutil import parser, relativedelta
>>> tzh=relativedelta.relativedelta(parser.parse(local), parser.parse(utc))
>>> tzh
relativedelta(hours=-5)
```

To format it the way you want:

```
>>> f"{tzh.hours:+03d}{abs(tzh.minutes):02d}"
'-0500'
```

Or, Python 2.6 to 3.5:

```
>>> "{hours:+03d}{minutes:02d}".format(hours=tzh.hours, minutes=abs(tzh.minutes))
'-0500'
```

The module `dateutil` isn't in the standard library but it is well worth the trouble of downloading. It can do far, far more than this.

Comment: I've done most of the work, but not all, since my problem is to get the offset as string in the specific format :) I edited my post since they question obviously is not clear: Is there a way to get "-0500" I need (string in that specific format, not a float), either by datetime library or string formatting?

Thanks for dateutil tip, I'll definatelly check it!

Comment: @rstk : extended the answer slightly. I didn't at first understand that the formatting was the point of the question. Which shows I didn't read it carefully enough.

Comment: thanks for the update, it helped, I used similar formatting with my code and got the same output. Now, problem with this solution is that is works fine only with time zones that are on hour. There are some time zones that are on 30 or 45 minutes. If offset is -3:30, we'd get "-0350" , not "-0330". That's why I wondered is there maybe some datetime trick, or another formatting, which deals with this properly.

Comment: Now I see you edited it again in the meantime, you realized the issue too. :) But it's still not okay for negative non-round time zone (got "-04-30", not "-0430").

Comment: Quite right, I only tested it with eastwards offsets from UTC. I forgot about Newfoundland (though I thought that was `-0330` not `-0430`). Fixed now. The use of `abs(minutes)` is safe because in this case the sign of the hours and the minutes will always agree.